How to Safely Add Users to Backend with Google Sign-In?
I’m working on a Flutter app with my own custom backend built in Django. Currently, I have a registration form that accepts an email and password to create a new user in the database.
Now, I’m integrating Google Sign-In and wondering how to handle new user registration. After a successful Google sign-in, I receive details like the email, idToken, accessToken, and user ID. I was thinking of sending a request to my backend with the email and using the accessToken as the password to create the user.
But is this a safe approach? Should I handle this differently to ensure the security of the authentication process? What’s the best way to securely add a new user to my backend using the data received from Google Sign-In?
I’m not using Firebase, just my own Django backend. Any guidance or best practices on how to implement this securely would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
